# Doctrine2 define collate and charset in yaml config file

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Hoy I can configure collate and charset in doctrine2 yaml config file ?

I have this config but seems that not work

```
Vulco\AppBundle\Entity\Garage:
    type: entity
    table: vulco_garage
    options:
        collate: utf8_general_ci
        charset: utf8
    repositoryClass: Vulco\AppBundle\Repository\GarageRepository
```

Thanks

> Edited: It works correct!

Comment: i do this with annotation, can should be useful if i post it as answer?

Comment: I think you should delete your question as the problem is not reproducible now.